# Is there a listener for triggers in database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I would like to know if theres a database **event** listeners in the Database.

I know we can write triggers are various levels.

But was wondering weather there are any process for listeners.

Triggers are picked up by the database. HOW its done is there a continuous trigger listening process running behind in database?

Thanks.

Comment: Listening for what?  What are you trying to do that you can;t do with triggers?

Comment: What do you mean? When a trigger's event occurs the trigger is executed. Please edit your question and clarify what you're attempting to do. Thanks.

Comment: The update / insert statement that you run _directly causes the 'database trigger'_ to be executed.

Comment: Maybe the OP is looking for a description of trigger's architecture/ design logic.

Comment: Thanks yes my question was naive and vague at that moment!.
I got some answers through colleagues which was exactly similar to : 
How to implement a db listener in Java (Link attached above in by moderator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listeners gets activated when following things takes place:

1. Insert
2. Update
3. Delete

This commands activates the listeners.

Comment: this is wrong. Triggers and listener have a clear meaning in the context of an oracle database, and there will no listeners be activated.But I have to admit that I do not understand the question that was posted. Maybe you are talking about [event listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) as they are known   in Java or a similar thing. But then this must be made clear in the question and the answer.